# C++, Why array is faster and use less memory than vector

Tags: c++, memory, runtime, std

During one leetcode question.
When I use `std::vector` to store things.
`i_max`, and `j_max` are integers.

```
vector<int> left_vec(i_max);
vector<int> right_vec(j_max);
```

Runtime: 100ms, Memory Usage: 71.5MB.

When I use `std::array` to store things.

```
int left_vec[i_max];
int right_vec[j_max];
```

Runtime: 40ms, Memory Usage: 16.1MB.

Other parts of the code are exactly the same, the only difference is using vector or array.

I am very confused about why this is the case.

Comment: Can we see your code? Are you passing vector's to functions by value (making copies)?

Comment: Also, how does leetcode compile your code, whether optimizations are turned on or not?   You should not rely on what leetcode does or any any other website where you cannot control the compilation process.  Do the testing on your own local machine with your local compiler, or go to a reputable benchmarking website for C++ code.

Comment: Also, why are you saying you use `std::array`, but the code you're showing uses non-standard C++ variable length arrays (unless `i_max` and `j_max` are constants)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie      i_max and j_max are integers.

Comment: @Blastfurnace those two vectors or two arrays are local variables I created inside one function.

Comment: Then the code you're showing isn't even valid C++.  The only way to have dynamic arrays in C++ is by dynamic allocation.  So your test has a lot of flaws.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I didn't expand their sizes, just the initial size, and fill in numbers.

Comment: That's still not valid C++. Standard C++ array sizes must be compile-time constants.

Comment: Again, that is not legal C++.  Arrays must have their sizes denoted by constants, not runtime values.  That means that in standard C++, you have no choice but resort to dynamic arrays using `std::vector` or `new[] / delete[]`.  The second thing is that declaring those non-standard arrays like that inside the function can blow out the stack memory if `i_max` and/or `j_max` are large.  With `std::vector`, there is no issue with that.

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your question.  See some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: Do you pass optimization flags?

Comment: Also want to comment that the syntax you are using is C style array, `std::array` goes like `std::array<typeName, size> arrayName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are a simple sequence of data allocated on the [stack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/).

Vectors are an object that probably is allocated on the [heap](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/). (I am not sure on that one for ALL cases, I think it might depend on the C++ std library implementation and compiler optimization depending on what you are doing with the vector. Two posts on that [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/129163/) and [here](https://www.quora.com/C-programming-language-Does-std-vector-use-stack-or-heap-memory-and-why?share=1). As a rule of thumb, consider it to be allocated on the heap).

One good intuition for you to have, even though not completely "technically accurate" and not related with what I just said about stack and heap.

An array is very simple, you give it a type and a size and that is all you have. It is your job to worry about not accessing a value outside the array's boundaries, how and where you save or access a value in the array, tracking the array's size...

A vector on the other hand is an entire object with lots of functionalities. It gives you many methods to help you insert, pop, read, check its size... This comes with a price.

Comment: *"Arrays are a simple sequence of data allocated on the stack."* - this is a very common misconception.  The important objection is that that's only true when the array - or some type containing it - is a function argument or local (automatic) variable.  It could also be static (namespace scoped), or on the heap (whether independently allocated as such or because it's a member of a type created there).  More strictly, if you switch between vector and array the objects themselves will be in the same place (heap, stack, static), but the *values stored* by a `vector` will always be on the heap.

Comment: Additionally, `vector`s store a pointer to the heap, and some data indicating their current runtime size and capacity (usually a pointer to the end of stored data, and a pointer to the end of heap storage, for 3 pointers), whereas `array`s only store the elements and it's up to the user to decide if they want/need to track which elements are in use.

Comment: @TonyDelroy that added a lot to my answer. If you have the power to edit my answer it would be great if you could add that information with your own words and remove anything I deem incorrect.

Comment: Hi Vinícius.  I'm not entirely comfortable with that as I'm afraid I don't feel any of your answer is both correct and relevant to the question.  The likely relevant things are an extra layer of dynamic memory allocation and deallocation, additional 0 initialisation on construction (and those are only likely to be relevant if the scope of the vectors is local to a loop).  Depending on how the vectors were accessed, there might be extra overhead (e.g. `at(n)` is more expensive than `[n]`).  OP didn't provide actual code either, so we can't eliminate other mistakes.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`vector`s are allocated on a heap, `array`s are on the stack.

Heap allocation takes time.